# Creating a simple auto complete textbox in thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to SpringBoot and thymeleaf and I'm trying to complete an auto complete text box which gives names of doctors as suggestions.But it doesn't work as expected and no any suggestion are shown.I have tried several ways and gone through several tutorials.

Here is my html code

```
 <label>Doctor Name:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{name}"  id="doctor_name">
```

Here is my relevant Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("#doctor_name").autocomplete({
        source: "nameAutoComplete",
        minLength: 3
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Here is my handler method in controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/nameAutoComplete")
public List<String> nameAutoComplete(@RequestParam(value = "term",required=false,defaultValue = "")String term){
    List<String> suggestions=new ArrayList<String>();
    suggestions.add("Andrew Bayes");
    suggestions.add("Asher");
    suggestions.add("Anthony");
    return suggestions;
}
```

}

And also I included following links according to the tutoral

```
<script th:src="@{https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js}"></script>
  <script th:src="@{https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js}"></script>
```

please give some suggestions to correct my approach.